# EBNF Nested Optional/Grouping

Tags: python, grammar, ebnf

I'm observing the python grammar listed in the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) and considering the outputs of their form of EBNF, specifically with varargslist:

```
varargslist: (vfpdef ['=' test] (',' vfpdef ['=' test])* [',' [
'*' [vfpdef] (',' vfpdef ['=' test])* [',' ['**' vfpdef [',']]]
| '**' vfpdef [',']]]
| '*' [vfpdef] (',' vfpdef ['=' test])* [',' ['**' vfpdef [',']]]
| '**' vfpdef [',']
```

Though I'm specifically interested in this section:

```
['*' [vfpdef] (',' vfpdef ['=' test])* ]
```

Which I interpret as:

```
[ [ non-terminal1 ] ( non-terminal2) ]
```

I realize that both

```
non-terminal1 (non-terminal2)
(non-terminal2)
```

Are valid options in this form, but does this include:

```
non-terminal1
```

as well? The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) page for EBNF states

```
That is, everything that is set within the square brackets may be 
present just once, or not at all
```

but does this group everything within the square brackets as one entity that may appear only once, or is the option selective, for example:

```
[ [non-terminal1] [(non-terminal2)] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
['*' [vfpdef] (',' vfpdef ['=' test])* ]
```

is

```
[ [ non-terminal1 ] non-terminal2 ]    -- parentheses deleted as redundant
```

then `non-terminal2` represents

```
non-terminal3 *
```

which is nullable by definition. (That is, it might be empty.)

So, strictly speaking, once you've done the transform

```
non-terminal1
```

is not a valid outcome. The parse must be

```
non-terminal1 non-terminal2
```

where `non-terminal2` has matched an empty string.

But the actual parse logic is more likely to want to use the formulation

```
[ [ non-terminal1 ] non-terminal3... ]   -- Not EBNF syntax, but I hope you get the idea
```

in which `non-terminal2` has been eliminated as a distraction from the resulting parse. In this case, since the 0-or-more repetition can be 0 repetitions, correct outcomes would include

```
                                          -- nothing :-)
non-terminal1
              non-terminal3
non-terminal1 non-terminal3
              non-terminal3 non-terminal3
```

and so on.